# Transaction emails going to Spam in magento

Tags: php, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, email-spam, transactional-email

All transaction emails of our website going to spam,
When i check the original message SPF,DKIM are Pass and only the default templates are activated.

How can we solve this problem?

Regards,

Comment: When I created an order the order confirmation email go to spam, although the templates are the default templates and I have marketplace their emails go to inbox only the magento transaction emais.

Comment: @Tomm when i use the contact form on our website i receive email in inbox only the transaction emails however the default templates are used.